# To extract non-nan values from multiple rows in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, dataframe, pandas

I am working on several taxi datasets. I have used pandas to concat all the dataset into a single dataframe.

My dataframe looks something like this.

```
                     675                       1039                #and rest 125 taxis
                     longitude     latitude    longitude    latitude
date
2008-02-02 13:31:21  116.56359  40.06489       Nan          Nan
2008-02-02 13:31:51  116.56486  40.06415       Nan          Nan
2008-02-02 13:32:21  116.56855  40.06352       116.58243    39.6313
2008-02-02 13:32:51  116.57127  40.06324       Nan          Nan
2008-02-02 13:33:21  116.57120  40.06328       116.55134    39.6313
2008-02-02 13:33:51  116.57121  40.06329       116.55126    39.6123
2008-02-02 13:34:21  Nan        Nan            116.55134    39.5123
```

where 675,1039 are the taxi ids. Basically there are totally 127 taxis having their corresponding latitudes and longitudes columned up.

I have several ways to extract not-null values for a row.

```
df.ix[k,df.columns[np.isnan(df.irow(0))!=1]]
              (or)
df.irow(0)[np.isnan(df.irow(0))!=1]
              (or)
df.irow(0)[np.where(df.irow(0)[df.columns].notnull())[0]]
```

any of the above commands will return,

```
675   longitude    116.56359
      latitude     40.064890 
4549  longitude    116.34642
      latitude      39.96662
Name: 2008-02-02 13:31:21
```

now i want to extract all the notnull values from first few rows(say from row 1 to row 6).

how do i do that?

i can probably loop it up. But i want a non-looped way of doing it.

Any help, suggestions are welcome. 
Thanks in adv! :)

Answer (score 5):

```
df.ix[1:6].dropna(axis=1)
```

As a heads up, `irow` will be deprecated in the next release of pandas. New methods, with clearer usage, replace it.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#deprecations

Comment: Thank you so much for the info. But apparently the command you mentioned is not what i want :( :( in a row, i need to extract all notnull values. => for several rows, without iterating, can i do it in a more compact way is the question. Thank you so much for replying :)

Answer (score 2):

In 0.11 (0.11rc1 is out now), this is very easy using `.iloc` to first select the first 6 rows, then dropna drops any row with a `nan` (you can also pass some options to dropna to control exactly which columns you want considered)

I realized you want 1:6, I did 0:6 in my answer....

```
In [8]: df = DataFrame(randn(10,3),columns=list('ABC'),index=date_range('20130101',periods=10))

In [9]: df.ix[6,'A'] = np.nan

In [10]: df.ix[6,'B'] = np.nan

In [11]: df.ix[2,'A'] = np.nan

In [12]: df.ix[4,'B'] = np.nan

In [13]: df.iloc[0:6]
Out[13]: 
                   A         B         C
2013-01-01  0.442692 -0.109415 -0.038182
2013-01-02  1.217950  0.006681 -0.067752
2013-01-03       NaN -0.336814 -1.771431
2013-01-04 -0.655948  0.484234  1.313306
2013-01-05  0.096433       NaN  1.658917
2013-01-06  1.274731  1.909123 -0.289111

In [14]: df.iloc[0:6].dropna()
Out[14]: 
                   A         B         C
2013-01-01  0.442692 -0.109415 -0.038182
2013-01-02  1.217950  0.006681 -0.067752
2013-01-04 -0.655948  0.484234  1.313306
2013-01-06  1.274731  1.909123 -0.289111
```

Comment: No actually thats not what i want. in your example, 2013-01-03 row's column B and C are needed. Only those columns with Nan values should not be considered. But really thanks for suggesting something.

Comment: If you only want to consider a subset of the columns, try ``dropna(subset=['C'])``

Answer (score 0):

Using Jeff's dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import randn

df = pd.DataFrame(randn(10,3),columns=list('ABC'),index=pd.date_range('20130101',periods=10))
df.ix[6,'A'] = np.nan
df.ix[6,'B'] = np.nan
df.ix[2,'A'] = np.nan
df.ix[4,'B'] = np.nan
```

We can replace nans by some number we know is not in the dataframe:

```
df = df.fillna(999)
```

If you want to keep only the non-null values without iterating you can do:

```
df_nona = df.apply(lambda x: list(filter(lambda y: y != 999, x)))
df_na = df.apply(lambda x: list(filter(lambda y: y == 999, x)))
```

The problem of this approach is that the result are lists so you lose information about the index.

```
df_nona
A    [-1.9804955861, 0.146116306853, 0.359075672435...
B    [-1.01963803293, -0.829747654648, 0.6950551455...
C    [2.40122968044, 0.79395493777, 0.484201174184,...
dtype: object
```

Another option is:

```
df1 = df.dropna()
index_na  = df.index ^ df1.index
df_na = df[index_na]
```

In this case you don't lose info about index, although this is really similar to previous answers.

Hope it helps!